# In Docker service creation API endpoint, what's the purpose for Command and Args parameters?

Tags: docker, docker-api

There's two distinct parameters in the [`/services/create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ServiceCreate) endpoint, called `Command` and `Args`. The description says:

- `Command` (array of string) – the command to be run in the image
- `Args` (array of string) – arguments to the command

I was puzzled by the fact that `Command` is an array: if the command arguments can be passed to it (which seems to be the case as docker-py [splits it as a shell command](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/1fc62e6a32c2d3257d5d033fcf924fabb16190ac/docker/types/services.py#L125)) what's the purpose of `Args` then?

Answer (score 0):

My current guess: the purpose of `Command` and `Args` is the same as in `Entrypoint` and `Cmd` in regular Docker containers. `Args` are just appended to the `Command`:

```
POST /services/create

{
  "Name": "test",
  "TaskTemplate": {
    "ContainerSpec": {
      "Image": "ubuntu",
      "Command": ["echo", "foo"],
      "Args": ["bar"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ docker service logs test
test.1.npltmr9c69fz@hostname    | foo bar
```

And if you omit the `Command`, it is taken from the image's entrypoint:

```
POST /services/create

{
  "Name": "test2",
  "TaskTemplate": {
    "ContainerSpec": {
      "Image": "ubuntu",
      "Args": ["echo", "baz!"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ docker service logs test2
test2.1.c16waqqxtdgd@hostname    | baz!
```

This is only a result of my empirical testing, so any solid documentation / source code proofs are appreciated!

Comment: (Kubernetes has the same "`command` is entrypoint, `args` is command" renaming; frequently an image will use `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time setup and it's useful to just pass a command as `args`.)